# 'Bash ./main: No such file or directory' error while trying to execute a C++ program

Tags: command-line, bash, c++, executable, g++

The code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int a, b, diff;
    cin>>a>>b;
    diff = a - b;
    if(diff % 10 == 9){
        diff--;
    }else{
        diff++;
    }
    cout<<diff;
    return 0;
}
```

The command used to compile:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

The error:

```
bash: ./main: No such file or directory
```

Error when 'main.o' is used:

```
bash: ./main.o: Permission denied
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp -o main
```

Don't use the -c flag if you want
to create an executable.

```
 ./main
```

If you press Tab it will autocomplete.

Comment: I get the error 'Permission denied', when I use 'main.o'.

Comment: I updated gcc command and renamed output file to main